# How does one convert a .NET tick to a python datetime?

Tags: .net, python, datetime, timestamp

I have a file with dates and times listed as huge numbers like 634213557000000000. I believe this is a [.NET tick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx). That's the number of 100 nanosecond increments since midnight on January 1, 1 A.D. What's a good way to read that into a [python datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object?

Comment: I think you're misusing the term epoch. An epoch isn't a number - it's the base from which the numbers count. So the epoch of .NET DateTime values is January 1st, 1AD. On many other systems (possibly including Python) it's January 1st 1970AD.

Comment: I was in the process of changing that to tick when you made this comment.

Comment: Wow, questions with .NET in the title get answered really fast!

Comment: Ah! they were ticks and obsoletes my answer

Comment: @pyfunc Yes, as @Jon also pointed out, I initially mis-labelled them as 'epochs' when I slapped this question together. I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(microseconds = ticks//10)
```

For your example, this returns

```
datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 29, 11, 15)
```

Comment: For Python 3 compatibility, you could use `microseconds=ticks//10`, to avoid loosing precision with floats.

Comment: @jfs apologies for not responding earlier, you made your comment over 5 years ago!  According to [PEP 238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) the `//` operator has been in place since Python 2.2, so there's no good reason not to update my answer with your suggestion.