# Time conversions in Python

Tags: python, time, timestamp

I am pulling a detection's history file from Kaspersky AV. In this file it denotes time with an 18 character numeric value (ex. 130900894153614080). I did a little research and I think this is called a .NET system timestamp. Is there a way to convert this to a human-readable timestamp using Python?

Comment: [`strptime` from datetime](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875806/how-does-one-convert-a-net-tick-to-a-python-datetime

Comment: thank you very much that answers my question ... Apreciate that very much sir