# .NET Date object to datetime in Python

Tags: python, .net, datetime

I got a .Net Date Object back from my get request that looks like this

`/Date(1503528300000-0500)/`

I see this post [Date conversion .NET JSON to ISO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786448/date-conversion-net-json-to-iso)
 about how to convert it to ISO. but how about Python `dateTime` (not php)? Ultimately I want to use `datetime.datetime.now()` to compare with the converted datetime and get the difference.

and can someone please explain what is the part after the `-`? in this case what is the `0500`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP date format /Date(1365004652303-0500)/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749778/php-date-format-date1365004652303-0500)

Comment: My inquiry clearly states Python not PHP

Comment: Core concept is the same

Comment: The 0500 appears to be the offset from UTC. Depending on DST, that could be Eastern or Central for North America.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one convert a .NET tick to a python datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875806/how-does-one-convert-a-net-tick-to-a-python-datetime)

Comment: @gillduck maybe it answers what components of .net object are. but it didn't explain how to do what I desires in python. so it didn't fully answer my question.

Comment: @JoseDzirehChong the .NET tick does not have the offset portion from UTC. It is not the same

Comment: @afilbert Thank you for the comment that is very helpful. Can you elaborate more on how the offset works?

Comment: If you know how to get the ISO with offset, then this may help on the python end: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3908349/119041

Comment: @J.Doe for sure. The offset is just the number of hours from "zulu" time, or UTC. The Z in an ISO 8601 date/time indicates Zulu time. You want to be careful with offsets, however, and double check whether they're standard or DST (daylight savings time). I recommend storing in UTC ALWAYS, then present according to local offset at the time (again, changes with DST).